# How to subtract 2 observables in RXJS 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6, combinelatest

I want to subtract 2 observable numbers

```
this.num1:Observable<number>
this.num2:Observable<number>
this.num3:Observable<number>

this.num1 = this.store.select(getNum1Count);
this.num2 = this.store.select(getNum2Count);
// this.num3 = difference of this.num1 and this.num2
```

in RXJS5 I was doing the below command

```
 this.num3 = Observable.combineLatest(this.num1,this.num2,(c1,c2)=> Math.abs(c1 - c2));
```

But in RXJS6, combineLatest is deprecated: Deprecated in favor of static combineLatest [as shown here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#dep-methods)

How do we make this to work in RXJS 6?

On trying the RXJS6 format of combineLatest,

```
combineLatest(this.num3,this.num2, this.num1, (c1,c2) =>  Math.abs(c1 - c2 )),filter(x => x !== NaN);
```

I get an error
 [The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cskqm.jpg)

Comment: Only result selectors are deprecated, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors-removed-or-deprecated

Comment: just use `combineLatest` directly: `combineLatest(this.num1,this.num2,(c1,c2)=> Math.abs(c1 - c2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with help ( via gitter @Dorus and @GuillaumeUnice )

```
this.num3 = this.num1.pipe(combineLatest(this.num2),map(([n1,n2]) =>  Math.abs(n1 - n2)));
```

Observation: As a developer it is weird when just a simple arithmetic operation is this complicated.

Comment: Well you're not doing a simple arithmetic operation, though. You're operating on two parallel streams of data over time. There's many ways to interpret what "subtracting" them could mean.

Comment: True. I forgot these were streams. It makes sense.